# Raising RAM in load BMP function SDL

Tags: c, sdl, ram

I'm using SDL to code a simple game, and i have a big problem - i'm trying to do some animations with function,
in the fuction i call static int which keeps raising every game tick, and dependant on value of static int i change my variable image (with image=SDL_LoadBMP(myfile)), it's working great, but after 10 minutes of running a program, which had been working with 50MB of memory before without this really simple animation, ram usage of my program is starting to get bigger and bigger, and as i said, after 10 minutes it's 3GB and keeps raising every animation occur(so, like every 3 seconds).

Weird thing is also that i have other image which animation is a little bit simplier - i change my image upon clicking any arrow (still in main), and then call function, so after a second it gives back the initial image to a variable(it's giving image back in function), and it's working great - with that i mean - even if i keep clicking arrows, memory usage is constant.

my function looks like that:

```
void func(obj* image)
{
static int time1;
time1++;
if(time1>1000)
{
time1=0;
SDL_FreeSurface(image->image); //this doesn't change anything
image->image=SDL_LoadBMP("path");
}
else if(time1>800)
image->image=SDL_LoadBMP("path2");
else if(time1>600)
image->image=SDL_LoadBMP("path3");
else if(time1>400)
image->image=SDL_LoadBMP("path4");
}

typedef struct {
    SDL_Surface* image;
}obj;

int main()
{
obj struct;
func(&struct);
}
```

ofc it's fulfilled with all this SDL library calls to make a window etc

https://i.ibb.co/YBcvjnF/Bez-tytu-u.png

Comment: You should `SDL_FreeSurface(image->image);` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: `struct` is a terrible name for a variable.

Comment: When i add SDL_FreeSurface(image->image); at beggining of function i get error: Exception 0x000000005E3DA0CD (SDL2.dll) in szablon2vs19.exe: 0xC0000005: Naruszenie zasad dostępu podczas odczytywania w lokalizacji 0xFFFFFFFF00000000.

Comment: i tried to make it much more simple than my program just to show what's the problem, that's why in this code name of my variable is struct, sorry for using that

Comment: just like @LegendofPedro said please don't name your obj structure `struct`, this is a reserved keywords in C ([more info here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword))

Comment: It works by now thanks to @BSO, im not sure if there is a way of closing thread or something, thank everyone anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're making `SDL_Surface*` over and over again, you never call `SDL_FreeSurface()`([info](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface)).

You need to load a some point all the BMP needed to play the animation into `SDL_Surface*` then reuse these BMP(s).

In your main (or into an init function) you need to store into an array or pointers the BMP images.

```
// Somewhere on one of your struct
SDL_Surface *animationImages[4];

// Then in an init function you do
animationImages[0] = SDL_LoadBMP("path");
animationImages[1] = SDL_LoadBMP("path2");
animationImages[2] = SDL_LoadBMP("path3");
animationImages[3] = SDL_LoadBMP("path4");

// And finally 
void func(obj* image) {
    static int time1;
    time1++;

    if (time1>1000) {
        time1 = 0;
        image->image = animationImages[0];
    } else if (time1>800) {
        image->image = animationImages[1];
    } else if (time1>600) {
        image->image = animationImages[2];
    } else if (time1>400) {
        image->image = animationImages[3];
    }
}
```

And before the end of your game or when you don't need these `animationImages` anymore call `SDL_FreeSurface()` for each `SDL_Surface*` you have created.

```
// In a specific function used to clean up allocated stuff you do
SDL_FreeSurface(animationImages[0]);
SDL_FreeSurface(animationImages[1]);
SDL_FreeSurface(animationImages[2]);
SDL_FreeSurface(animationImages[3]);
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i understood you well, but i already tried to do in function something like that: (at if(time>1000){ SDL_FreeSurface(image->image); image->image=SDL_LoadBMP … } ) and the memory keep raising

Comment: @Lidbey Perfect to close the thread you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), so when people will search similar questions they will see this question has an accepted answer.